# Screen recording along with webcam (Picture in picture) - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, webcam, video.js, screen-recording

I am working on a web application in which I need to give my customers a facility to record screen along with camera recording in a corner of the screen, just like in tutorials.

[image]

It is almost done and both are working fine but some issues are bothering me, like:

**Camera view hides on other screen**
    As I'm working in web, so when I minimize the browser (to record desktop or another window), the camera part hides as well as it is in browser.
    [image]
    Can I make the camera part stick, when I change tab or window???

**Separate audio & screen recordings**
    Audio is not being recorded with screen, but it is being downloaded separately as a video file, recorded using webcam.
    [image: enter code here]
    I want to download all (audio, video & screen) as one file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Camera view hides on other screen

An approach to achieving this could be that you record the web camera video stream separately from the screen recording and then merge them together after the recording is finished, using `ffmpeg` or a similar video editing tool.

I'm not aware of any way that you can have Chrome draw video or anything outside of the browser, right onto your screen desktop.

#### Separate audio & screen recordings

Again, you'll need to merge the different streams together. You can do this either by merging the audio stream into the screen video stream, with the [`addTrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack) method on the MediaRecorder API, or with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I want to have all in one file, because merging them together explicitly can be easily done (and actually I've done it already using VLC). Still Thank you so much for your help.